# Continuous Integration - How to use artifacts from 2 builds but only triggered by 1 build

Tags: continuous-integration, teamcity

I am using TeamCity for CI works.

Currently I have a build configuration which requires artifacts from two config (A & B), but I want the build to be triggered only when there is successful build from A, but use the artifacts from A and also B's last successful build.

My current setting is

```
Triggers = Finish Build Trigger - Wait successful build from A

Artifacts Dependencies - A & B, both pointing to same checkout dir
```

But all the times i only get the artifacts from A

Any idea?

Edit: Dependencies Rules, same for build A & B, clean destination option unchecked.

```
+:output/* => %system.teamcity.build.checkoutDir%/%build.number%/
```

Comment: i guess the problem in the `Artifacts rules` you are using. Could you please add the `Artifacts rules` to your question and are you using `Clean destination paths` in the artifact dependency rule?

Comment: @daggett added artifacts rules, clean destination option is unchecked in both artifact dependencies.

Comment: Try `**/* => A` for A, and `**/* => B` for B, so in checkout dir two folders will appear `A` and `B`